# What does green screen on 3gs mean?

Tags: iphone

The iphone 3gs went off (did not use it for a couple of days). I attached it to its power cord but all I can see is green screen.

Tried resetting it with power_btn+home_btn, but still the same. tried connecting it to pc usb via its cable, and it did not help either.

can anyone help?

Comment: Your display is dead. Just to confirm, post a picture.

Comment: @duci9y it's not.r ead my comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try connecting it to a PC or Mac and use iTunes to restore the device. It's not likely software is causing this, but you will know if the rest of the phone works and possibly fix it without needing to take it in for hardware service if the display function is broken.

You won't be able to tell if it's the screen or the cable or the video subsystem without replacing parts or getting into the hardware to at least reseat the cables but this is most likely a hardware failure.

Comment: it seems it was over depleted (battery). I left it over the night connected to pc and it was ON this morning. is this usual thing with iphones? I do not use them much

Comment: My experience is that when the voltage is too low to operate the phone, you get no backlight and no images displayed on the device. I'm glad it's resolved with a good charge, but if it happens repeatedly my bet would be some other hardware failure is preventing the device from detecting the low voltage (or causing low voltage to the video system). Hopefully it keeps working when charged or plugged into power for as long as you need it. It is normal for the device to restart itself when power is totally dead once it determines it has sufficient voltage to operate.